# Error "Failed to retrieve SDK status from server" in Xamarin iOS with VS 2012

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

While loading Solution of Xamarin iOS in Visual Studio 2012, I am getting and Error "Failed to retrieve SDK status from server"

Someone suggested to disable proxy but on which PC, windows or on MAC and how to disable proxy that was also not mentioned.

Could anyone please help me get rid of this error?

Answer (score 4):

I was properly paired to a build host (using Visual Studio 2013) but was also getting this error. I got this to work by making sure I had the build configuration platform set to `iPhoneSimulator.`

`Build -> Configuration Manager -> Platform (for my iOS project) -> iPhoneSimulator`

This was apparently set to `iPhone` by default and I don't have any physical devices attached, so I have to use the simulator.

Answer (score 2):

Also tried, just to let you know, when I did a clean install of Xamarin, I would get this error message in the Build Server log file:

Error: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/share/doc/MonoTouch/MDocArchiveToMsxDocConverter.exe not found Apple Docs need to be updated.

I had to copy the converter file from here: /Developer/MonoTouch/share/doc/MonoTouch/MDocArchiveToMsxDocConverter.exe

to here: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/share/doc/MonoTouch/MDocArchiveToMsxDocConverter.exe

But it still hasn't fixed the build error I'm getting. Any advice is appreciated, as I've tried everything I can think of at this stage from using clean machines, re-installing everything, etc.

**Edit 2**

While looking solution for above mentioned issue, found another issue of "No Device Found" in my simulator list for which the solutions is  [here] ([No devices attached in xamarin VisualStudio for ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888823/no-devices-attached-in-xamarin-visualstudio-for-ios))

**Edit 3**

Please check time settings in both windows & MAC PC, if the time is not synchronized then this problem may occur.
Please **vote up "+"** if any of the above mentioned solution did work for you. :)

Comment: 3rd solution helped me! There were 3 minutes time difference between 2 machines.

Comment: @ttotto glad to hear that solutions worked for you. :)